# How to profile a C++ shared library written for python

Tags: python, c++, pybind11, intel-vtune

I am writing a library for some scientific computing tasks, where the core computational routines are written in c++ and pybind11 is used to expose them to the python side of the library.

How can I profile my c++ code to improve the performance. In particular, how can I use intel-vtune profiler with my python scripts that call the c++ functions.

Comment: I have used `vtune-gui` with my binary but I get the error that no data was collected in the result. Though I see in my terminal that the wrapper script was executed successfully.

Comment: Python is not magical. The interpreter is just a normal C program. Can you use vtune to profile a hello world C program?

Comment: I didn't get your question ?

Comment: Write a very simple program in C. Profile it with vtune. What happens? Do hou get any errors?

Comment: Ok, I don't have any issues with that. I actually compile my C++ code as a shared object, and within the c++ code I use pybind11 to expose the c++ function to python. Now, the only way I see to test them is through python scripts that call them. vtune does allow one to use wrapper script with the binary. When I use it I see that no data is collected.

Comment: It isn't quite clear what exactly "use wrapper script with the binary" should mean. Your simple program is an executable and you can profile it. The Python interpreter is another executable and you should be able to profile it the same exact way. If the interpreter loads a shared library somehow (via a script and pybind11, or by any other means) you should see profile data for that library.

Comment: I hear vtune supports profiling Python scripts and this might be what you have tried to do. I am not familiar with this functionality.

Comment: Have you compiled your shared library with debug symbols (`-g` for gcc or clang)? They are usually necessary to get any meaningful profiling results. Note that you should nevertheless compile with optimizations enabled.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. I just made a simple pybind11 module and profiled it in hotspot mode with vtune, twice. Once by profiling the python executable and once by profiling the script. Either way the data was collected just fine.

Comment: Presumably the bit you're interested in profiling is your "core computational routines", not the marshalling done by pybind. In which case, why involve Python in it at all? Write performance tests in C++ and profile those.

Comment: @DanMašek I get what you are saying, but writing performance tests in python is much easier.

Comment: @n.m. Could you may be write post your example as an answer?

Comment: Just copy the first toy example from the pybind11 site. It is literally it.

Comment: Hi @Fracton , We could reproduce your issue. Hence, we have forwarded this issue to the respective team. Apologize for the inconvenience caused!